# Ellipsis in array initialization in C kernel module

Tags: c, kernel

I was examining some code on github https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/v4l2loopback.c and came across this line, which baffles me. Is this some incredibly cool kernel macro or gcc feature that I don't know about? What does the `= -1` do?

```
static int video_nr[MAX_DEVICES] = { [0 ... (MAX_DEVICES-1)] = -1 };
module_param_array(video_nr, int, NULL, 0444);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(video_nr, "video device numbers (-1=auto, 0=/dev/video0, etc.)");
```

The line in question is the first, the next two given for context (this is creating a cmdline-specifiable parameter using a kernel macro http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L103 )

Anyway, what is going on with the array initialization? How does that syntax work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize an array with a single value in C (GCC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780405/initialize-an-array-with-a-single-value-in-c-gcc)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've found an example of [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).  C99 & C11 don't go quite as far as your example, but they have some pretty flexible support for this kind of behaviour.  Your specific example (using the `...`) is a GCC extension.  From the link:

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write `[first ... last] = value`. This is a GNU extension. For example,
>
> ```
> int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
> ```

So that means your example is creating an array of size `MAX_DEVICES` and initializing every element in that array to `-1`.

For reference, the only standard-supported behaviour is to assign specific indices, rather than ranges:

> [constant-expression] = initializer-value

There is a more complicated example in my copy of the spec:

```
int a[MAX] = {
            1, 3, 5, 7, 9, [MAX-5] = 8, 6, 4, 2, 0
};
```

Which initializes the first five and last five elements of the array to explicit values.  The middle values (if any) would be `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I hope my question was not a bit noobish, but googling for "array ellipsis" did not help me... I guess it's not a widely-used feature.

Comment: I don't think it's too noobish - this feature is considered pretty exotic and isn't widely used.

Comment: I guess my inability to locate this is a sacrifice of the fact that punctuation isn't weighted very well in search results, so even "..." doesn't do much, and the page doesn't say "ellipsis" explicitly.

Comment: There was a repeat notation for initializers in Fortran IV (Fortran 66)! It is a great pity that C has not remembered this and standardized on the GNU extension (which is entirely backwards compatible, and would complete the designated initializers support – and has prior art to prove it is implementable).

Comment: Please, could you show that syntax in your comment? I'm interested.

Comment: @dmi_, I think what Jonathan means is that the C standards people should standardize the GNU syntax (the `...`), not that they should appropriate the Fortran syntax.