# System call Table in x86 (ia32)

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls

I'm studying how system calls are implemented in the Kernel code, and I'm focusing in the x86 architecture, however, I'm having a tough time understanding the assembly code, and the part where it acesses (or call the function?) of the system call table (the entry.S file, as far as I understand, uses the macros to "prepare" for the system call), and the part that's a mystery for is:

```
ia32_do_call:
  IA32_ARG_FIXUP
  call *ia32_sys_call_table(,%rax,8) # xxx: rip relative
```

Since I'm using the website [lxr.free-electrons.com](http://lxr.free-electrons.com), I used the free-text search to see how is the function implemented for further understanding. I've come across this:

```
const sys_call_ptr_t ia32_sys_call_table[__NR_ia32_syscall_max+1] = {
   /*
    * Smells like a compiler bug -- it doesn't work 
    * when the & below is removed.
    */
    [0 ... __NR_ia32_syscall_max] = &compat_ni_syscall,
#include <asm/syscalls_32.h>
};
```

What's happening here?

Comment: It's an array of function pointers. What exactly is the "mystery"?

Comment: The mystery to me is how he accesses the function pointer, and where? Because he gets the pointer to the system call needed, but where it's executed?

Comment: The `call` obviously invokes the function selected from the table. PS: even though you say ia32, that code is the compatibility layer in the 64 bit kernel, not the true 32 bit entry point.

Comment: And where do I find this function? Whatever the system call, just to understand the step-by-step...

Comment: Which function? The actual table is in the file `<asm/syscalls_32.h>` which is a generated file. It contains entries like: `__SYSCALL_I386(1, sys_exit, sys_exit)` which are created from `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`. `sys_exit` itself is defined in `kernel/exit.c`  as `SYSCALL_DEFINE1(exit, int, error_code)`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, just a final question, where can I find the code of the system call? I mean, the getpid(), where is the function and the commands behind it?

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit surprised by this file as well, so I'll leave a few pointers to help you out if you get here.

First of all, `sys_call_ptr_t` is defined in `include/asm/syscall.h` as:

```
typedef long (*sys_call_ptr_t)(const struct pt_regs *);
```

Therefore `ia32_sys_call_table` is an array of function pointers, as we expect.  Next, this array is initialized with a gcc extension known as [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513067/ellipsis-in-array-initialization-in-c-kernel-module)).  The first part of the initialization sets each entry of the table to point to a function called `sys_ni_syscall` (I'm pretty sure, it seems to get created through a bunch of macros...).  This is defined in a file `kernel/sys_ni.c`:

```
/*                                                   
 * Non-implemented system calls get redirected here. 
 */                                                  
asmlinkage long sys_ni_syscall(void)                 
{                                                    
    return -ENOSYS;                                  
}
```

Finally, the inclusion of the file `<asm/syscalls_32.h>` can be understood by looking at two things.  First of all, go to `entry/syscalls/`, and run

```
bash syscalltbl.sh syscall_32.tbl gen.c
```

and take a look at the contents of `gen.c`.  Now, look at this macro from `entry/syscall_32.c`:

```
#define __SYSCALL_I386(nr, sym) [nr] = __ia32_##sym,
```

At this point, with maybe a little more `grep`ping around, this file should not be so mysterious.