# Three dots operator "..." for initializing an array

Tags: c, operators, variadic-macros

Consider the following example which initialize an array with a default value:

```
static unsigned int array[10] = { [ 0 ... 9 ] = 5 };
```

What exactly this operator does?

It is related to variadic macro `__VA_ARGS__`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize an array with a single value in C (GCC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780405/initialize-an-array-with-a-single-value-in-c-gcc)

Comment: No, it is not related to variadic macros or variadic functions.

Comment: This is not C.  The token `three dots` is not valid in the context of the indices of an array in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard C, since C99, designated initializers allow to initialize individual elements of an array in the form:

```
int array[4] = {[1] = 42};
```

The syntax you stumbled upon is a range initializer, it is a GNU extension to initialize all elements between `0`and `9` to the given value, thus strictly equivalent to:

```
static unsigned int array[10] = { [0] = 5, [1] = 5, [2] = 5, [3] = 5, [4] = 5, [5] = 5, [6] = 5, [7] = 5, [8] = 5, [9] = 5};
```

only less a burden to type and read.

[Reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

Comment: I'm thinking this example should instead end with:
, [9] = 5 };

Comment: @jaygeek You're right! Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in ISO C. It's a nonstandard construct.

In GNU C (gcc/clang) it [appears to initialize each of elements 0 through 9 to 5](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-Yn8oK), i.e., it's shorthand for (C99)

```
static unsigned int array[10] = { [0]=5, [1]=5, [2]=5, /*...*/ [9]=5 };
```

or (C89)

```
static unsigned int array[10] = { 5, 5, 5, 5, /*...*/ };
```

The `...` extension also works for `case`s:

```
_Bool lowercase_eh(char c)
{
    switch(c) case 'a' ... 'z': return 1;
    return 0; 
}
```

Apart from using the same `...` token, it is unrelated to variadic macros or fucntions.